# Android - Call method from an Activity from a Thread

Tags: android

I have the following snippet:

```
public class SocketActivity extends Activity {
.
.
.
EditText textView;
Socket socket = new Socket(name,ip);
out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
out.flush();
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
.
.
.
}
```

Now, I have other lines to allow this activity to converse with a java server. But what I would like to do, is create a thread that constantly listens for a message from the server. Currently, it only listens for a response after I send a message. How would I set the textView from the thread? Is this the best way to do this? If not, where else should I do this?

======================

So, here is a more complete description of what I want to do, the textView is too primitive for what I want. So I have a **MainActivity** that creates a superclassed **SurfaceView** which has a superclassed **Renderer** that contains a **Cube** object with buffers, so it can be drawn. I also have a **SocketActivity** to connect to a server

What I want to do is wait for the server to send a packet of points to the client. Then, as each point is received it is put into the buffer. Then, once it completes, it waits again for the next packet. How should I use Asynctask be used to put a point to a buffer everytime I receive one. So to get a map of what's going on:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    OpenGLSurfaceView view;
    .
    .
    .
}
public class OpenGLSurfaceView extends SurfaceView {
    OpenGLRenderer renderer;
    .
    .
    .
}
public class OpenGLRenderer extends Renderer {
    Cube cube;
    .
    .
    .
}
public class Cube{
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    .
    .
    .
}
public class SocketActivity extends Activity {
    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Now where should the Asynctask be instantiated? Should I structure my program this way, or is there a better way? (For those that do not know, to put a primitive into a buffer you use *buffer.put(/*primitive*/)*, but this is trivial.)

Comment: look into using `AsyncTasks`, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify UI (in this case TextView) from non-UI thread. Try using AsyncTask. The UI can be modified ONLY in  onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() methods. If you need example of how to use AsyncTask, please ask for.

There is another way to use Runnable with the method runOnUiThread() but, I recommend AsyncTask.

Example:

```
private class Surgery extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  private String dataSurgery=null;
  private File fileSurgery=null;

     public Surgery (String data1, File data)   //constructor
  {
        this.dataSurgery = data1;  //this is just example here you can put anything you want
        this.fileSurgery = data;
   }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //OPERATION WHICH IS UI-INDEPENDENT LET'S SAY SOMETHING LIKE THIS:
   Socket socket = new Socket(name,ip);
   out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
   out.flush();
  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));                        return "here you return data for the textview or anything you need";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // HERE YOU UPDATE YOUR TEXTVIEW i.e HERE YOU UPDATE ANYTHING WHICH IS ON THE UI 
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    // This is OPTIONAL, you might find you dont need to use it. 
    }


     }
}
```

Comment: Could I have an example of how to use Asynctask, please?

Comment: Also, where does this Asynctask go? Does it replace anything?

Comment: Nope, put it inside your current class as private, then create constructor(inside Surgery class) if you want to pass some data like 

public Surgery (String data1, File data)
{
   //here inherit the data for the Surgery class
   this.dataNeeded = data1;
   this.file = data;
}

and then call where you need it like

new Surgery("whatever", fileToDoOperation).execute("");

Comment: Hmm, recieve all points (calling SocketActivity, then call Rendering[i'm not in graphics that much, but i think this does not draws anything, it is only processing) at one time, split them in two array or other structure you wish, do this in doInBackground() method.
-----------------------------------------------
Calling of other class can be done in THESE methods depending if it draws or not, then do the drawing IN the onPostExecute(), then call the AsyncTask in the MainActivity as I mentioned before...